# "incrond dead but subsys locked" what does it mean?

Tags: linux, process

While running "service incrond status" it shows "incrond dead but subsys locked". 
Can you please tell me what does it means. Normally its status should be running. Let me know what may cause it to dead?

Comment: This is upstart right?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the service `incrond` crashed or got killed forcefully.

When a service is started, it touches a lock file (normally at `/var/lock/subsys`). This lock file is removed only when the service is stopped. When the service/program crashes, it will not get 'the chance' to remove the lock file and in such a situation, even though the service won't be running, this lock file will exist. When you check the status of that service in addition to checking for whether the process is running, it will also check for the existance of the lockfile in /var/lock/subsys. It will see that the service is not running, but the lockfile exists and hence it will print out this message.

This is what happened when I gave a `kill -9` to `auditd` service (1050 was the pid of auditd)

```
[root@merapp01 run]# kill -9 1050
[root@merapp01 run]# ll /var/run/1050
ls: cannot access /var/run/1050: No such file or directory
[root@merapp01 run]# ll /var/lock/subsys/auditd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 30 04:25 /var/lock/subsys/auditd
[root@merapp01 run]# /etc/init.d/auditd status
auditd dead but pid file exists
[root@merapp01 run]#
```

Now, when the service was stopped gracefully:

```
[root@merapp01 run]# /etc/init.d/auditd stop
Stopping auditd:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@merapp01 run]# ll /var/lock/subsys/auditd
ls: cannot access /var/lock/subsys/auditd: No such file or directory
[root@merapp01 run]# /etc/init.d/auditd status
auditd is stopped
[root@merapp01 run]#
```